# How can I used multiple file I receive in "request.FILES"?

Tags: python, forms, post, request, multipartform-data

If "request.FILES" have multiple file, how can i use it?
I want to get data from input tag(type="file" name="file" multiple) and upload this data.

i can use just one image. But not multiple. =(

```py
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print(request.FILES) 
    #<MultiValueDict: {u'file': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: emo1.png (image/png)>, <InMemoryUploadedFile: emo2.png (image/png)>]}>
    if 'file' in request.FILES:
        print(request.FILES['file'])
        #emo2.png
        #there is only one image left....
```

```py
for file in request.FILES['file']:
    #i want write upload file code
```

Comment: `for f in request.FILES.getlist('file'):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
files = request.FILES.getlist('file')
for file in files:
    pass
```

Read more about it in [Django's official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploading-multiple-files).